# How to make scroll appear on the left instead of the right? (CSS)

Tags: css, scroll

How would I make my scrollbar appear on the opposite side of my text? (current code makes it appear on the right.)

```
#words {
overflow-y: scroll;
max-height: 100px;
color:white;
margin: 30px 50px 30px 60px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: smaller;
font-weight: 300;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `direction:rtl;` [source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp)

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/jsm5bxkd/4/) to validate.

```css
.MainDiv {
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div>list 1</div>
  <div>list 2</div>
  <div>list 3</div>
  <div>list 4</div>
  <div>list 5</div>
  <div>list 6</div>
  <div>list 7</div>
</div>
```